# Combining two select SQL queries into one

Tags: mysql, sql

```
"id"    "type"  "parent"    "country"   "votes" "perCent"
"1"     "1"     "0"         "US"        "0"     "0"
"2"     "3"     "1"         "US"        "105"   "0"// Total
"3"     "10"    "2"         "US"        "15"    "0"
"4"     "10"    "2"         "US"        "50"    "0"
"5"     "10"    "2"         "US"        "25"    "0"
"6"     "10"    "2"         "US"        "5"     "0"
"7"     "10"    "2"         "US"        "10"    "0"

"8"     "1"     "0"         "US"        "0"     "0"
"9"     "3"     "8"         "US"        "80"    "0"// Total
"10"    "10"    "9"         "US"        "10"    "0"
"11"    "10"    "9"         "US"        "5"     "0"
"12"    "10"    "9"         "US"        "15"    "0"
"13"    "10"    "9"         "US"        "20"    "0"
"14"    "10"    "9"         "US"        "30"    "0"
```

In the above table `likes`, I have the total votes stored in a type = 3 row.

I'm trying to update the `perCent` column with the percentage of votes each has got where type = 10.

I do this right now in php like below. Can the first two statements be combined into one? I lost trying with joins and inner joins etc.

The way I currently do things in php is as follows:

```
select id, votes as totalVotes from likes where type = 3 and country = 'us';

select votes from likes where parent = id and type = 10;

update votes set votes = (100*10/totalVotes) where type = 10 and parent = id;
```

Results I trying to achieve:

```
"id"    "type"  "parent"    "country"   "votes" "perCent"
    "1"     "1"     "0"         "US"        "0"     "0"
    "2"     "3"     "1"         "US"        "105"   "0"// Total
    "3"     "10"    "2"         "US"        "15"    "14.28" (100*15/105)
    "4"     "10"    "2"         "US"        "50"    "47.61"
    "5"     "10"    "2"         "US"        "25"    "23.80"
    "6"     "10"    "2"         "US"        "5"     "4.76"
    "7"     "10"    "2"         "US"        "10"    "9.53"

    "8"     "1"     "0"         "US"        "0"     "0"
    "9"     "3"     "8"         "US"        "80"    "0"// Total
    "10"    "10"    "9"         "US"        "10"    "12.5"
    "11"    "10"    "9"         "US"        "5"     "6.25"
    "12"    "10"    "9"         "US"        "15"    "18.75"
    "13"    "10"    "9"         "US"        "20"    "25.00"
    "14"    "10"    "9"         "US"        "30"    "37.50"
```

Comment: Is the multi level hierarchical structure of type 10's a typo or intentional? Is id=4 supposed to have id=3 as parent, or id=2?

Comment: Type 10 are products. Type 3 is the heading for those products.

Comment: That's why I'm asking, product 3 is in this case a heading for product 4.

Comment: Yes. Its a heading for 4, 5, 6 and 7. Id 9 is the heading for 10, 11, 12, 13, 14

Comment: If both type 10 (id 3) and type 3 (id 9) can be headings for products, I can't see your code working, since it seems to assume a headings are type 3. Could you add an example of desired output?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that. I made a mistake when formatting the code for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you're asking, updating all products' percentages to reflect their part of the total votes under their heading;

```
UPDATE likes p
JOIN likes h
  ON p.parent = h.id
 AND p.type=10 AND h.type=3
 AND h.country = 'US'
SET p.percent=100*p.votes/h.votes;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6323/1).

Comment: It does :) Tack så mycket. In my efforts I never thought of doing a direct update. But your solution changes everything.

Answer (score 1):

Check [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90aa3/3) .

```
UPDATE `votestable` v
SET v.`percent` = (SELECT
                     ROUND( ( ( v.votes * 100) / v1.votes ), 2 )
                   FROM (SELECT
                           votes,
                           id
                         FROM Votestable) AS v1
                   WHERE v1.id = v.parent)
```

Comment: You came very very close. I was updating my answer. Maybe you can check.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, this looks like a left join to me.

```
SELECT lp.id, lp.votes + COALESCE(SUM(lc.votes), 0) as totalVotes FROM likes lp
    LEFT JOIN likes lc ON lc.parent = lp.id AND lc.type = 10
    WHERE lp.type = 3 AND lp.country = 'us'
```

Comment: This should be an INNER JOIN, not LEFT JOIN, since it won't returning any rows with no match in `lc`.

Comment: An INNER join would return no rows if there were no matches in lc, not a LEFT join, hence the coalescing for potential null values on the lc table joined on the right of the original table

Comment: But since your `WHERE` clause has `lc.type = 10`, it can never return any null rows. You need move that to the `ON` clause if you want to return null rows.

Comment: You're absolutely right on that part, answering questions at 3AM is indicative of me needing to be quiet and go to bed lol